# C getline function

Tags: c, strings, reinventing-the-wheel, io

I was looking for a C function that reads lines of arbitrary length from a file. I didn't find anything absolutely portable and safe from buffer overflows, so I tried writing my own.

- Does it look like I made any memory management mistakes?
- Does it make sense to have this function return `NULL` everywhere that it does?
- Have I made any other mistakes?

```
char *getaline (FILE *file)
{
    size_t buffsize = 120; /* The minimum size for a line buffer */
    size_t this_char = 0;

    if (file == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    char *line = (char *) malloc(buffsize);
    char **linebuff = &line;
    if (*linebuff == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    char c = getc (file);
    if (c == EOF) {
        return NULL;
    }

    while (1) {
        if (this_char + 1 >= buffsize) {
            buffsize = 2 * buffsize;

            char *next_linebuff;
            next_linebuff = (char *) realloc (*linebuff, buffsize);
            if (next_linebuff == NULL) {
                return NULL;
            }

            *linebuff = next_linebuff;
        }

        (*linebuff)[this_char] = c;
        this_char++;

        if (c == '\n' || c == EOF) {
            break;
        }

        c = getc (file);
    }

    (*linebuff)[this_char] = '\0';
    line = *linebuff;
    return line;
}

int main (int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r"); 
    char *line = "";

    while ((line = getaline(file)) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might write a full response later if someone else hasn't already, but the first thing that jumps at me is that there are two possibilities for memory leaks in the function.

Comment: Also, have you considered just using fgets?  Even if you don't use it directly, your function could be built on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for existing solutions, check out `readline`.  It's a pretty common library on *nix and even has [a Windows port](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/readline.htm).

As for a critique of what you posted:

```
char *line = (char *) malloc(buffsize);
```

Don't bother casting a `void*` to another pointer type.  This is a C++ thing.  In C you don't have to do it, the conversion can be done implicitly.

```
    char c = getc (file);
```

This is a common portability pitfall.  A `char` cannot represent the full range of characters and also `EOF`.  Depending on the environment you may not be able to distinguish between `EOF` and byte 255, or you may not be able to detect `EOF` at all.  Store the result of `getc` in an `int`, because that's what it returns.

```
char *line = (char *) malloc(buffsize);

// (snip)

char c = getc (file);
if (c == EOF) {
    return NULL;
}
```

If you hit that `return` you will leak the allocation of `line`.

Now, you could introduce a `free` inside the `if` block...  But many C programmers (myself included) prefer to avoid early `return` statements, because what happens is you end up with repetitive "free all the buffers" cleanup blocks.  Instead of doing an early `return`, I like to let the scope own the allocation, meaning I insert the `free` whenever something like `line` goes out of scope, having the same cleanup block run in a success or failure case.  (This sort of imitates C++'s RAII pattern, but with C and more manual.)

```
    if (this_char + 1 >= buffsize) {
        buffsize = 2 * buffsize;
```

These integer operations can overflow.  Maybe that's not a huge deal (I'll admit, I myself write a lot of code that doesn't handle overflow), but something to be aware of, should you be allocating sizes around the boundaries of the type of the size variables.

```
        next_linebuff = (char *) realloc (*linebuff, buffsize);
        if (next_linebuff == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }

        *linebuff = next_linebuff;
```

<s>Looks like you've successfully avoided the "leak on `realloc` failure" issue that traps many newbies.</s> (**Update:** Sorry, must have suffered temporary blindness, you do leak here.)  But I think this is too verbose.  Why do you need to maintain `linebuff` as a double pointer?  You already have `line`.

```
(*linebuff)[this_char] = '\0';
line = *linebuff;
```

Seems like you missed a potential `realloc` here.  If the buffer is exactly full when you hit that line, you'll write past the allocation.

```
while ((line = getaline(file)) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", line);
}
```

You never call `free` on `line` here.

---

My improved version follows, taking most of these suggestions.  I've tried to keep your code mostly the same and follow the same style.

```
char *getaline (FILE *file)
{
    size_t buffsize = 120; /* The minimum size for a line buffer */
    size_t this_char = 0;

    if (file == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    char *line = malloc(buffsize);

    if (line == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    int c;

    do {
        c = fgetc(file);

        if (this_char + 1 >= buffsize) {
            buffsize = 2 * buffsize;

            char *next_linebuff;
            next_linebuff = realloc (line, buffsize);
            if (next_linebuff == NULL) {
               free(line);
               line = NULL;
               break;
            }

            line = next_linebuff;
        }

        if (c == EOF || c == '\n') {
            c = 0;
        }

        line[this_char++] = c;
    } while (c);

    return line;
}

int main()
{
    char *p = NULL;
    while ((p = getaline(stdin)) && *p)
    {
       puts(p);
       free(p);
    }
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why set `line = NULL` if it's always set to `next_linebuf` before the next iteration? Is it just-in-case programming practice?

Comment: @afuna There is no next iteration in the case you're describing.  ```line = NULL``` appears after ```free``` and before ```break```, then gets returned to the caller.  We can't return a stale pointer.  In general though, I do like to null out pointers after a call to deallocate.

Comment: oops... I wasn't paying attention to the scope re. the `break`. my bad.

Answer (score 2):

I see no need for the variable `linebuff`. In every location it is used you just de-reference it. Which makes it the same as `line` anyway. So wherever you use `*linebuff` just use `line` instead.

```
    char **linebuff = &line;
```

Here you are potentially leaking `line`.
At every return point you need to make sure you clean up any allocated memoty.

```
    if (c == EOF) {
        return NULL;
    }
```

I think your loop is the wrong way around.
Normally when reading a line I would not add the new line character to the buffer (but that is a debatable point). Which you seem to be trying to do with the condition at the end. But if the first character is a new line then you add it to the buffer (because you don't test `c` that was read outside the loop.

```
    while (1) {
```

You could simplify this by doing the read (and all the tests at the top).

```
    int c; // note `c` should be an int.
    while((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
        {    break;
        }

        // Now do all the work to add the character to the buffer.
```

Another potential leak.
If realloc() fails then the original buffer is not affected. So you will need to release it if you return NULL.

```
            char *next_linebuff;
            next_linebuff = (char *) realloc (*linebuff, buffsize);
            if (next_linebuff == NULL) {
                return NULL;
            }
```

Also I don't like the two line call to realloc(). I would declare and do the assignment in a single line:

```
            char *next_linebuff = realloc (line, buffsize);
```

In main() you get a dynamically allocated string from a function. Documentation is scetchy but it looks like you should be taking ownership. Which means you are also responsable for clean up (ie freeing the string).

```
while ((line = getaline(file)) != NULL) {
```

Where each call to getaline() means the result of the last call is leaked.

Your line doe not contain a new line.
So when you print it, it may be a good idea to add the new line back

```
    printf("%s", line);
```

It should look like this:

```
char* line;

while ((line = getaline(file)) != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", line);
    free(line);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have dissected your function thoroughly.  In case you are interested, an alternative method of accessing a normal file (but not a socket, pipe, etc) is to use `mmap`.  This maps the whole file into memory without the need to `malloc` anything.  The allocation occurs in the background as you access the mapped file - which for a text file now looks just like a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

static void fail(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main (int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    (void) argc;
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        fail(argv[1]);
    }
    struct stat st;

    if (fstat(fd, &st) < 0) { /* to get the file size */
        fail(argv[1]);
    }
    void *const map = mmap(0, st.st_size,
                           PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, 
                           MAP_FILE|MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    if (map == NULL) {
        fail(argv[1]);
    }
    char *term;
    char *s = map;

    while ((term = strchr(s, '\n')) != NULL) {
        char ch = *term;
        *term ='\0';          /* replace the '\n' so we can print the line */
        printf("%s\n", s);
        *term = ch; 
        s = term + 1;
    }
    if (*s) {                 /* if last line has no '\n' */
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
    munmap(map, st.st_size);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You definately have memory leaks.

```
==92867== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==92867== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==92867== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==92867== Command: ./a.out test1
==92867== 
--92867-- ./a.out:
--92867-- dSYM directory is missing; consider using --dsymutil=yes
abc
def
ghi
==92867== 
==92867== HEAP SUMMARY:
==92867==     in use at exit: 10,815 bytes in 38 blocks
==92867==   total heap usage: 38 allocs, 0 frees, 10,815 bytes allocated
==92867== 
==92867== LEAK SUMMARY:
==92867==    definitely lost: 480 bytes in 4 blocks
==92867==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==92867==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==92867==    still reachable: 10,335 bytes in 34 blocks
==92867==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==92867== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==92867== 
==92867== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==92867== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Furthermore, It segfaults on me when I give it lines longer than 119 characters. (But this is probably system dependent).

```
$ ./a.out test3 ; cat test3
abc
this is a test
this is a line with 40 characters in it
this is a line with 119 characters in it..............................................................................
Segmentation fault: 11
abc
this is a test
this is a line with 40 characters in it
this is a line with 119 characters in it..............................................................................
this is a line with 120 characters in it...............................................................................
```